# Eclipse-Requested resource is not available.

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run a simple html file ( as a part of a project) in Eclipse IDE but am getting the error

The requested resource (/auction_portal/index.html) is not available.

Following is the message that I get in my console.

```
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;D:\Software\eclipse;;.
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 381 ms
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\docs is unusable.
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\examples is unusable.
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory host-manager
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\host-manager.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1051)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory manager
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1051)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\_ is unusable.
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Feb 6, 2013 11:33:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 403 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

There is clear indication in the log:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache 
Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\
host-manager.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Check all `SEVERE:` messages and see where those files exist.

Comment: @gursheel07 `host-manager.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)` what is not clear here?